# Как можно реализовать шифровщик текста в СИ?

Tags: c

Я пытаюсь написать шифровщик текста с использованием простой перестановки по столбцам. Ключем выступает слово,которое вводится через консоль,каждой букве этого слова присваивается столбец,после чего буквы из слова сортируются по их положению в алфавите и отсортированные вместе с буквами столбцы выводятся в консоль.
Я не могу понять как можно реализовать "присваивание" букве из слова определенного столбца... Можете подсказать какие-то варианты?
В голову приходит только сделать из каждой буквы отдельный массив,в котором будут буквы из столбца,принадлежащему этой букве. Это реализуемо? Важно что бы это можно было сделать именно в СИ.

Comment: дайте ссылку на алгоритм, который пытаетесь закодить.

Comment: @KoVadim Вот wm-help.net/lib/b/book/3167518757/175